# bash - if command output is NOT null, write output to a file

Tags: bash, if-statement

I feel like this should be very, very, easy... but somehow I can't figure it out.

The matter is simple. I have the following if statement, which I'm  using to check IPs and see if they have a reverse DNS or not. If there is a valid Reverse DNS available, I write it to a file. If not, I write "NXDOMAIN" to the same file.

```
if [[ $(dig +noall +answer -x 10.10.10.10 | grep -m 1 PTR | awk '{ print $5 }') ]]; then
       dig +noall +answer -x 10.10.10.10 | grep -m 1 PTR | awk '{ print $5 }' > /root/IP
else
       echo "NXDOMAIN" > /root/IP
fi
```

This works OK, but it runs the command twice, unnecessarily. Is there a way in which, if the command returns a valid reverse DNS, I can output it directly to a file, without running the command again?

So, basically, something like this:

```
if [[ $(dig +noall +answer -x 10.10.10.10 | grep -m 1 PTR | awk '{ print $5 }') ]]; then
       <write output of the above command in the "/root/IP" file>
else
       echo "NXDOMAIN" > /root/IP
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not store it in a variable like so:

```
RevLookup="$(dig +noall +answer -x 10.10.10.10 | grep -m 1 PTR | awk '{ print $5 }')"
if [[ "$RevLookup" ]]; then
       echo "$RevLookup" >> /root/IP
else
       echo "NXDOMAIN" >> /root/IP
fi
```

Comment: Thanks, it surely works. I did not mention the fact that I had this if statement in a for loop, and for some reason I did not think to include a variable directly in the for loop. I tried it now and works flawlessly!

Comment: Awesome glad to help. Note I did add `>>` to your `echo` statements so you will append to the output file rather than overwriting it every time you loop.

Comment: You can just use `echo "${RevLookup:-NXDOMAIN}" >> /root/IP` instead of an `if` statement.

Comment: Thanks @JohnK. I know, in fact I'm using `>>` in my actual script. this was just a quick example :)
@chepner, yes, indeed, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @chepner is there a name for what your method is called. I want to go read the documentation on that... really cool.

Answer (score 1):

Put the result in a variable.

```
REV_DNS=$(dig +noall +answer -x 10.10.10.10 | grep -m 1 PTR | awk '{ print $5 }')
if [[ $REV_DNS ]]
then
    echo "$REV_DNS" > /root/IP
else
    echo "NXDOMAIN" > /root/IP
fi
```

Comment: Don't forget your semi-colon on the `if`